# Google apps script very slow when running function from a different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries

I have 2 google spreadsheets A & B each with its own embedded code. I sometimes call function in B from A and vice versa with libraries(A & B are libraries to each other). My problem is even a simple function like below takes a while to run. Is there a way to make it faster?

`function test() {
  return "hi";
}`

Comment: So you have deployed A and B as libraries to use in each other code, and that works. I don't know if there is an actual way to *magically* sped up the code. What do you mean by "takes a while"? Expect code deployed as library to be slower than code right there in Apps Script editor.

Comment: If we can’t reproduce the problem we can’t fix it.

Comment: If i run the script in just A it takes like less than 5 seconds for it to execute, but if I run it as library it takes at least 30 seconds to execute. I am also sending the message to Slack as a bot so maybe it is Slack that is slow.